# Total digits are inconsistent

Tags: php

I m using following code to get random hex values. But the output is inconsistent
Sometimes it returns 6 digits sometimes 5 digits

```
function generateHexValue($length=6) 
{
    $chars = "0123456789abcdef";

    $i = 0;
    $str = "";

    while ($i<$length) {
        $str .= $chars[mt_rand(0,strlen($chars))];
        $i++;
    }

    return $str;    
}

$col=generateHexValue();
echo "<div style='background-color:#".$col."; width:100px; height:100px;'></div>";
echo $col."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 6):

Your call to `mt_rand()` should have a max of `strlen($chars)-1`, not `strlen($chars)`. The max of `mt_rand` is inclusive. You could get an index off the end of `$chars` array (e.g. `$chars[16]`, which is an undefined offset into `$chars`). Not sure what PHP would make of that.

Comment: Absolutely right. You may even receive an empty string. Your string last char index is 15, while `strlen($str)` returns 16. `$str[16]` is empty, so nothing is appended to your string.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `mt_rand(0,strlen($chars))` returns a number between 0 and 16 (inclusive), but your `$chars` string only has the offsets 0 - 15. A classic off-by-one mistake.

Answer (score -2):

`substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 6)` does the same thing but faster.

Comment: `I haven't looked at the code to see what might be wrong` That's not a good start for an answer...seriously not.

Comment: In addition it will be faster since you are running little interpreted code although I doubt that's a concern.

Comment: @Bobby The subject screamed the poster was doing something which has been done a million times, why not go with what's tried and tested

Comment: Hit enter by mistake. As an analogy if someone asked you to look at the code they wrote to read a file into an array(delimited by '\n'), would you debug the code or ask them to use the function file()?

Comment: Both...there are reasons to write your own code. Sometimes it's also a trimmed down example of real code or a simple exercise. At least look at his code or at least don't write that you haven't even read it, because that sounds like `I have read the title and I know you're doing it wrong so do it my way`.

Comment: @Bobby I guess you are assuming I didn't even glance at the code, that's not the case. I saw a function which can be replaced by a much cleaner solution. Even if it's part of an application, the function can be changed easily. I have no idea where you get the idea that I am imposing this on him. I have basically said 'I think my solution seems better than yours, and frankly I think you are doing it wrong'. But I'm not his boss, he's free to choose any solution he wants. I could go on but I hope you have got the point.

Comment: `I guess you are assuming I didn't even glance at the code, that's not the case.` I quote from your answer `I haven't looked at the code to see what might be wrong...` I think we have a little communication problem here, because as I read your answer you didn't even glance at the code. If you want to suggest a different solution, feel free to do so. Don't forget to completely outline your approach so that the OP can easily follow it. I'm revoking my downvote, please edit your answer so that it can't be misunderstood.